# Cannot gitignore codeception.yml file in Laravel 5?

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am working with codeception in Laravel 5 and I have a codeception.yml file sitting in my base project directory which I want to ignore because it has database credentials which vary across machines.

**.gitignore** file:

```
/.phpstorm.meta.php
/_ide_helper.php
/vendor
/node_modules
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.env
.env.testing
codeception.yml
```

I thought this should do it. But git is still tracking the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you already committed that file to git in the past?

Comment: Oh yes, I think I would have to remove it too somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have committed the file in the past you will need to remove it from the cache try

```
git rm --cached codeception.yml
```

Even if you add a file/directory to the `.gitignore` file if it has been added to the repo in the past then git will remember it.

> it has database credentials which vary across machines.

If you have accidentally committed sensitive data you may want to follow the advice [Github give here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

## Update

To prevent link rot here are the summarised instructions from the above link on removing secure data from a repo. If you wish, there is also a simpler version by using the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) package.

1. In a terminal `cd` to the local clone of the repo in question.
2. Run the follow (Be careful! This will overwrite your existing tags.):

   ```
   git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
   'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch codeception.yml' \
   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
   ```
3. Add the `codeception.yml` file to your `.gitignore` and commit.
4. After checking the state of your repo `git push origin --force --all`
5. If you need to remove the sensitive data from your tags you will also need to run `git push origin --force --tags`
6. Tell your collaborators to rebase, not merge. Merging will reintroduce the files.
7. After some time has passed and you're confident that git filter-branch had no unintended side effects, you can force all objects in your local repository to be dereferenced and garbage collected with the following commands (using Git 1.8.5 or newer):

   ```
   git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
   ```

   Then

   ```
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all
   ```

   Then

   ```
   git gc --prune=now
   ```

Comment: Glad it worked, if you need to remove the file from the repo history completely follow the github link posted. I will updated the answer later with full instructions to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already added codeception.yml file to the git index before adding it to .gitignore. That's why it is being tracked by git.

You can use the following command to remove it from git index so that it won't be tracked any more. But keep in mind, this will remove the codeception.yml file from all other locations where you take pull after pushing these changes, except your local copy.

```
git rm --cached codeception.yml
```